# How to iterate xsl nodeset and getting each node in string format

Tags: xslt

I am working on  an xslt to iterate a nodeset. 
Iteration is working perfect, but it's type is to be converted to  string. How should I do it?

```
<xsl:for each select =" ext:node-set($References) ">
    <test><xsl:value-of select="."></test>
    </xsl:for-each >
```

How should I get the value of  each  item  in  string  format  within  test  tags?

Comment: Please provide complete and well-formed documents like suggested/forced in [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us as your input, stylesheet and at least expected result(s).

Answer (score 0):

Use `copy-of` if you want the nodes and not their string value:

```
<xsl:for each select =" ext:node-set($References) ">
    <test><xsl:copy-of select="."></test>
</xsl:for-each >
```